# Building Openssl 1.0.1l libraries with no-ssl3 support for Windows does not disable SSL3

Tags: windows, openssl

I tried building openssl 1.0.1l (https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz) binaries on Windows with following configuration command `Configure no-ssl3 VC-WIN32` followed by `ms\do_ms` and `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`.

It successfully builds the binaries but when I try make a request using SSL3 it was successful. 
Can anyone please help me to disable SSL3 on 1.0.1l branch of openssl.

Note: Using same command on openssl 1.0.1j disabled ssl3 from binaries and so when I use ssl3 request it quits (which is expected)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 1.0.1l and before, which is fixed in OpenSSL 1.0.2.

[Reference](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/CHANGES):

```
*) Build option no-ssl3 is incomplete.

 When OpenSSL is configured with "no-ssl3" as a build option, servers
 could accept and complete a SSL 3.0 handshake, and clients could be
 configured to send them.
 (CVE-2014-3568)
 [Akamai and the OpenSSL team]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the configuration was changed by this?

[no-ssl3 configuration sets method to NULL (CVE-2014-3569)](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20150108.txt)

## no-ssl3 configuration sets method to NULL (CVE-2014-3569)

Severity: Low

When openssl is built with the no-ssl3 option and a SSL v3 ClientHello is
received the ssl method would be set to NULL which could later result in
a NULL pointer dereference.

This issue affects all current OpenSSL versions: 1.0.1, 1.0.0 and 0.9.8.

OpenSSL 1.0.1 users should upgrade to 1.0.1k.

OpenSSL 1.0.0 users should upgrade to 1.0.0p.

OpenSSL 0.9.8 users should upgrade to 0.9.8zd.

This issue was reported to OpenSSL on 17th October 2014 by Frank Schmirler. The
fix was developed by Kurt Roeckx.